# How to get the type-level values of '[String] in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation

I can get the value of a type-level `String` in the following manner:

```
> :set -XDataKinds
> import Data.Proxy
> import GHC.TypeLits
> symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy "test")
"test"
```

How do I go about getting the values of `'[String]`, such as `Proxy :: Proxy '["a", "b", "c"]`? I'd like to be able to iterate through the values in code.

Comment: You'd want to enumerate the types of the kind 'String ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be solved by making another typeclass:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
import Data.Proxy
import GHC.TypeLits

class ManySymbolVal (xs :: [Symbol]) where
  manySymbolVal :: proxy xs -> [String]

instance ManySymbolVal '[] where
  manySymbolVal _ = []

instance (KnownSymbol a, ManySymbolVal as) => ManySymbolVal (a ': as) where
  manySymbolVal _ = 
    symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy a) : manySymbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy as)

myProxy :: Proxy '["hello","small","world"]
myProxy = Proxy

main :: IO () 
main = mapM_ putStrLn (manySymbolVal myProxy)
```

Comment: Thanks! Does this mean that there is no built-in way to iterate through a list at the type-level and a custom type class must be used?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no better way of doing it than with typeclasses and there are no functions in the `base` package for iterating through type-level lists. However, there is the handy dandy `typelits-witnesses` package that packages up traversals for type-level lists of `Nat`s and `KnownSymbol`s. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/typelits-witnesses-0.2.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits-List.html#t:SymbolList // I believe underneath the hood it is using the same technique as presented in this wonderful answer (see the source for the `KnownSymbols` class and instances).